# Tensorflow image.central_crop (mis)behavior

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the Tensorflow documentation for [tf.image.central_crop](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/image/cropping#central_crop) function:

```
Remove the outer parts of an image but retain the central region of
the image along each dimension. If we specify central_fraction = 0.5,
this function returns the region marked with "X" in the below diagram.

 --------
|        |
|  XXXX  |
|  XXXX  |
|        |   where "X" is the central 50% of the image.
 --------
```

Consider the following code:

```
In [2]: import tensorflow as tf
In [3]: image_raw = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
In [4]: image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_raw, channels=3)
In [5]: crop = tf.image.central_crop(image, central_fraction=0.5)
In [6]: init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
In [7]: sess = tf.Session()
In [8]: sess.run(init_op)
In [9]: image_np, crop_np = sess.run([image, crop],
   ...:     feed_dict={image_raw: open("/tmp/test.jpg", 'rb').read()})
In [10]: image_np.shape
Out[10]: (456, 450, 3)
```

Original image size is 456x450

```
In [11]: crop_np.shape
Out[11]: (228, 226, 3)
```

Crop size is 228x226

Which gives area ratio of:

```
In [12]: 228*226 / (456*450.)
Out[12]: 0.2511111111111111
```

Not 0.5 as I expected. Can someone help to clarify this?

Comment: well, obviously height is off by 1...

Comment: It looks like this is returning 50% of each dimension, which would result in an image 25% of its original size.

Comment: Yes, but that's something different from `"X" is the central 50% of the image` written in the doc, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

As @Wes Doyle pointed out, it returns 50% of each dimension, which is consistent with the illustration in the comments, the original size is 4x8 (4 "|" signs and 8 "-" signs), and the cropped size is 2x4 (2 "X" vertically, 4 "X" horizontally).